# show image on GridView win 8 metro style?

Tags: windows-8

I follow step by step this article(http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-step-by-step-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom/) to add Images to GridView of my project, but when I finish adding GridView to my project following this article. I had a problem with showing image is that the image( in the project folder) don't show when the app is running but the app shows images from internet(the code from article has run well and loaded the image from project folder), I don't know how to show this problem,

this is some code:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }   
}

public class MovieCategory
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Items { get; set; }
}
```

My code to load image from project folder:

```
 MovieList.Add(new Movie { Title = "The Ewok Adventure", Category = "Adventure", Subtitle = "The Towani family civilian shuttlecraft crashes on the forest moon of Endor.", Image = "duy.jpg" });
```

(I've create MovieList before, and image "duy.jpg" is in the folder of project)

I don't why I try above code with source from article,i've checked image source string carefully by debug tool, it worked well(image from project folder was showed in source of article) but when i added to my project,the image from internet link worked well but the image from project folder didn't load.
    Please help me.Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change class definition like this

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }   

    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
         get
         {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///" + this.Image));
         }
    }
}
```

And bind Image tag with `ImgSource` property not with `Image` property.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" ........./>
```

Answer (score 0):

is the image in project root ? did you set to Content and Always copy to output folder ?

Comment: the image from root folder,I've set the Build Action to content and Always copy to output folder but there's no change. It can't load image from root folder.The source from article work well with image from root folder.